# If I'm returning a new anonymous type from a Linq-2-Entities query, do I need to detach them from the context?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, dto

After a set of L2E entities have been returned, we copy the data into new plain data transfer objects (DTOs) that aren't attached to the data context.  We do that, because otherwise changes to those entities could be detected and persisted to the database unintentionally when data is saved.

If instead of returning an entity that represents a real database record, I'm returning an anonymous type, could I just return such instances normally without worrying about copying their data into new objects first?  Such an anonymous entity could represent a join across multiple tables and might not even have an ID in the end, so I'd imagine changes to such objects couldn't be tracked/detected anyway.  If they are somehow, could I just detach them from the context instead of copying them before returning them?  Or can I just return them without worrying about detaching them?

Answer (score 1):

anonymous types or non "entity types" are never tracked. So you can

```
from a in context.Table select new { x = a.X }
```

or

```
from a in context.Table select new NonEntityType { x = a.X }
```

You can also:

- use `AsNoTracking()`
- manage the life cycle of your context: make modification out of a living context
- detach your entities from the context: beware side effects on graph = related entities will be set to null